# how to use standardstyles.xaml in Visual studio 2013 on windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-7, visual-studio-2013

Kindly help me to use standardstyles.xaml in Visual studio 2013 on windows 7.My ultimate need is to use style property with some default style templates in VS-13 on windows 7.
i am trying to use the below code for my button design.but i am unable to get any of the default style template.
"Button style="{staticresorce navigationbackbutton}"".But i am getting error as                          "The member "style" is not recognized or is not accessible."

Comment: It would be useful to attach the "below code" :)

Comment: actually my code and error result is there in the description but it is not appearing if i save that..please find below the same."Button style="{staticresorce navigationbackbutton}"".But i am getting error as                          "The member "style" is not recognized or is not accessible."